# how to get selected categoryIds in magento 2?

Tags: magento-2.1, catalog, category-products, adminform, admin-controller

I want to get selected categoryId to save it :

```
 $productObj->setCategoryIds(selectedCategoryId);
 $productObj->save();
```

[image]

Comment: where you want to  **get selected category Id**

Comment: in my action can you give me any idea please I try this                                  $cat_ids = $productObj->getCategoryIds(); 
but it give me categoryIds of selected products  
I want to get just selectedCategoryIds in my form

Comment: I try this but var_dump($category) ==> null                                                                                
 $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
        $category = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Registry')->registry('current_category');
        var_dump($category);die;